# How to move backup logs (1 year retention logs) from log analytics workspace to azure storage account

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-log-analytics, azure-storage-account, azure-log-analytics-workspace

I am trying to fetch 1 year retention logs from azure log analytics workspace and push it to storage account.

Tried data export option but it is pushing the logs from the time I had enabled Data Export, not the retention logs.

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding, in your case **`Data export`** in **Log Analytics workspace** starts exporting data(new), formed from the ***configuration time*** of Data export rules. So, you are getting the logs formed after enabling the **`Data export`** but not the retention logs.

Please check whether you have configured **retention time** as per your requirement.

> As per this [Microsoft Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/logs/log-analytics-workspace-overview#data-retention-and-archive), Data in a **Log Analytics workspace** is retained
> for a specified period of time after which it's either removed or
> archived with a reduced retention fee. Set the **retention time** to
> balance your requirement for having data available with reducing your
> cost for data retention.

To know how to set **retention time**, follow below steps:

***Go to Azure Portal -> Your Log Analytics Workspace -> Usage and Estimated Costs -> Data Retention***

[image: 1]

To do this from **PowerShell/CLI**, find this [link](https://www.shudnow.io/2019/10/14/increasing-azure-log-analytics-retention-per-data-type/)

Data Retention may also differ based on the **`pricing tier`** you are using. To know more about that in detail, please go through this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/service-limits#log-analytics-workspaces).

You can also try using **other export options** as mentioned in this [Microsoft Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/logs/logs-data-export?tabs=portal#other-export-options).

If you are still facing any issue, please find below references if they are helpful.

**References:**

[Troubleshooting why Log Analytics is no longer collecting data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/logs/manage-cost-storage#troubleshooting-why-log-analytics-is-no-longer-collecting-data)

[Other options to export data from Log Analytics workspace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/logs/logs-export-logic-app#other-export-methods)

[Data Collection Rules in Azure Monitor - Azure Monitor | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/essentials/data-collection-rule-overview)